# filling NAN and converting to int pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe of integers. Preview (starts from 3 due to first 3 rows removal):

[image]

The original data in the 'pixel1' column is `int`, but the `NAN` there forced it to `float`.

I tried to fix it with:

```
X_train.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
X_train = X_train.astype(int)
print(X_train.head())
```

that results in:

[image]

- can I get the datatype of the value the `fillna` is using?
- is there a better way to do so? *(better = to skip the `astype` step, as the data is `int` originally - I planted the `NAN` in the file and that caused the int to float unwanted data conversion...)*

Comment: `fillna` uses the same data type the column already has. What do you mean "a better way", is there something wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Answered inplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use `ffill` with `bfill` for back filling if possible some `NaN`s in first row:

```
X_train = X_train.ffill().bfill().astype(int)
```

If not:

```
X_train = X_train.ffill().astype(int)
```