# Pandas: Best way to remove NaN from multiple columns and convert them to int

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have below CSV data:

```
col1,col2,col3,label
,1,2,label1
3,,4,label2
5,6,7,label3
```

What is the best way to read this data and convert col1 & col2 which would be float to int.

I am able to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484145/filling-nan-and-converting-to-int-pandas) and convert my filtered dataframe which only has the numeric columns (col1,col2,col3). How can I modify the main dataframe itself ignoring the label column which is string?

On a related note, I could also use below command. Any idea how I could run it in a loop so that variable name col%d is dynamically generated, since I have 32 columns.

```
filter_df.col1 = filter_df.col1.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: To iterate over the 32 columns you could use this approach getattr builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `np.number`:

```
print (filter_df)
   col1  col2  col3   label
0   NaN   1.0     2     NaN
1   3.0   NaN     4  label2
2   5.0   6.0     7  label3

cols = filter_df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
filter_df[cols] = filter_df[cols].fillna(0).astype(int)

print (filter_df)
   col1  col2  col3   label
0     0     1     2     NaN
1     3     0     4  label2
2     5     6     7  label3
```

Comment: Note to readers: `select_dtypes` will return a new DataFrame and select the  columns from there.

Comment: @coldspeed - sure, what is problem with it?

Comment: No problem, just mentioned to readers who feel memory efficiency is important :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fillna` with `downcast='infer'`.

```
m = df.dtypes == np.number
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].fillna(0, downcast='infer')
print(df)
   col1  col2  col3   label
0     0     1     2     NaN
1     3     0     4  label2
2     5     6     7  label3
```